# Aligning rows of buttons with a title in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am really bad with CSS and I am trying to align rows of buttons with a title. My current display looks like:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
}

.listofbuttons{
}

.button {
  margin: 2px;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='title'>This is a title</div>
  <div class='listofbuttons'>
    <button class="button">Button 1</button>
    <button class="button">Button 2</button>
    <button class="button">Button 3</button>
    <button class="button">Button 4</button>
    <button class="button">Button 5</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am looking to do is have all the buttons align with each other, while remaining centered with the title. I have tried floats and changing the text align, but as you can probably guess that makes it so the buttons are not aligned with the title.

The caveat is that the number of buttons that are added to the list is not known, so it could be 1 or it could be 100. I am also trying to avoid using left margin/padding, to keep it consistent across screen resolutions.

The output would want looks like the following(without using a margin):

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
}

.listofbuttons {
  margin-left: 125px;
}

.button {
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='title'>This is a title</div>
  <div class='listofbuttons'>
    <button class="button">Button 1</button>
    <button class="button">Button 2</button>
    <button class="button">Button 3</button>
    <button class="button">Button 4</button>
    <button class="button">Button 5</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDITS:

Update removing the fixed widths.

Comment: I am confused. What do you actually want? Can you maybe add a picture showing the layout you want?

Comment: The second code snippet shows what I want, but without having to use `margin-left: 20px;`

Comment: .title { width: 100px; margin: auto;} .listofbuttons { width: 312px; margin: auto;}

Comment: @EvikGhazarian That doesn't change how the buttons are aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the width from the buttons themselves, and give their container a width of 75% and a display type of grid:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {}

.listofbuttons {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.button {
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='title'>This is a title</div>
  <div class='listofbuttons'>
    <button class="button">Button 1</button>
    <button class="button">Button 2</button>
    <button class="button">Button 3</button>
    <button class="button">Button 4</button>
    <button class="button">Button 5</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll give this a try right now and update.

Comment: If this solution worked in IE, I would have used it. It fits in the cleanest with my existing code, but I do need the cross-browser support.

Comment: Thanks again! This solution works really well with what I have done already.

Answer (score 1):

To horizontally center `.listofbuttons` you can add `margin: 0 auto` and `width` / `max-width` to it.

You need to set the right `width` to the buttons, which in your case seems to me like it should be `calc(33.3333% - 4px)`.

Then, to position/align them properly, you can either use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox), [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) (as others have suggested) or `float: left`, just like you were doing:

**Flexbox solution:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
  margin: 8px 0;
}


.listofbuttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.button {
  font-family: monospace;
  margin: 2px;
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.3333% - 4px);
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='title'>This is a title</div>
  
  <div class='listofbuttons'>
    <button class="button">Button 1</button>
    <button class="button">Button 2</button>
    <button class="button">Button 3</button>
    <button class="button">Button 4</button>
    <button class="button">Button 5</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**`float: left` solution:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

.listofbuttons {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button {
  font-family: monospace;
  margin: 2px;
  width: calc(33.3333% - 4px);
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='title'>This is a title</div>
  
  <div class='listofbuttons'>
    <button class="button">Button 1</button>
    <button class="button">Button 2</button>
    <button class="button">Button 3</button>
    <button class="button">Button 4</button>
    <button class="button">Button 5</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flexbox won't snap the buttons to a grid on subsequent rows. Grid is a better solution here.

Comment: @symlink It will. Feel free to add/remove buttons on the example above to see how everything stays in 3 columns, even when using `float: left`. The problem here is not the layout system, is basically the missing `margin: 0 auto` and `width` on the parent.

Comment: @Danziger I'll give your solution a try as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're looking for, but if you want to horizontally or vertically align elements within a container, you can use flex.

```
.listofbuttons{
display: flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
}
```

This will make any children of listofbuttons be aligned with each other. By default, it will align them horizontally.

I suggest you take a look at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Flexbox won't snap the buttons to a grid on subsequent rows. Grid is a better solution here.

Comment: The OP is looking for a solution to just horizontally align the buttons though. Why use Grid? Flex auto scales, and is a better solution for one dimensional layouts

Comment: Their "outcome" example shows the buttons aligned with each other horizontally and vertically